# What is exactly happening when I set a method to its own return value?

Tags: ruby

So I had this bug where I had a method:

```
def returnArr
  [2,3,4]
end
```

And I did this:

```
returnArr = returnArr.first
```

returned an error stating that nilClass doesn't have a method 'first'

Moreover, after doing that line of code, and follow it up with this:

```
returnArr = returnArr().first
```

worked completely fine, and returnArr is now different from returnArr(). What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have this line

```
 returnArr = returnArr.first
```

Ruby sees (and executes) this:

```
 returnArr = nil
 returnArr = returnArr.first
```

Before assigning value to a variable, this variable is initialized to `nil`. So, in this case, your local variable shadows your method. Without hints from your side, ruby can't determine that actually you wanted to call the method. When you provide parentheses, ruby understands that local variable can't have them and calls the method.

Don't ever do this again. Especially in a real app.

Comment: Thank you, that makes complete sense now. I didn't know that it sets returnArr to nil at first. And I would never do this, it was more experimental :)